# What are the Concentric Ring Connectors On Wireless Capsules called?

Tags: wireless

Does anyone know what the connector is called which has the center dot and two concentric rings around it found on Shure, Lectrosonics etc wireless systems? I'm sure, like XLR or TRS its got some sort of simple & catchy name, but nobody seems to specifically reference it in their literature!

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

update:
Here is a picture of what I'm talking about
[image: https://picasaweb.google.com/105618230887896249713/7171102#5630423181002493778]

Comment: Wow, that totally beats me! I'm surprised that isn't a proprietary thing--does that show up on virtually all wireless capsules? Ah, and for a sense of scale, these are handheld mics we're talking about, right?

Comment: Yep! http://www.amazon.com/Shure-PGX2-SM58-Wireless-Transmitter/dp/B0019RYOY6 its located below the SM58 tip down where that first ring is there right above the switches. I know, I have been looking for what this connector is called for quite awhile now. No product literature says, but its used by most of the major wireless manufacturers (I think all with the exception of Sennheiser)

Comment: The literature I can find seems to be calling it a "standard thread-on capsule." Perhaps there's no name for the "connector" per se, since it's not actually a cable interlink, nor does it have any uses outside of connecting a mic capsule to a wireless transmitter.

Comment: I'll buy that. Its just so unusual that nobody would come up with some name for it. I mean its spring clips (or pogo pins) which make contact with a circular PCB trace. That seems like the kinda thing that someone would have named. But I guess for now we will stick with what we have been calling it, thread on concentric traces! Thanks for your help

Comment: If I had to communicate this to someone I'd probably call it a bullseye connector or something like that. No clue what the technical term for it is though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a coaxial antenna interlink? This is commonly a [BNC connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_connector):
[image: BNC Connector]

It has a center pin and a sleeve contact for shield, and then a movable locking mechanism around the entire connector.

Comment: This type of connector is also often used for analog and SDI video connections.

Comment: I would post a picture on here, but sadly since I dont have enough reputation I cant. But no I'm not talking aobut a BNC (which only has two conductors) I'm talking about a 3 conductor system. I will try to add a link to a picture of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Could it be [Triax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triaxial_cable)?

Comment: No, its not a connector in that sense. There is no cable involved, its 3 PCB traces which make contact with pins on the head of a handheld wireless transmitter. if I can just get 4 more reputation points quickly I can show you a picture of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Heh, I gave you 5... One more shot: [Mixi XLR](http://static.bhphotovideo.com/images/items/425365.jpg)?

Comment: I know, thank you for your time! And I actually DO use those frequently, (I'm an engineer who works for a microphone manufacturer) so I'm generally surprised that there is no literature or names available for the connector I'm looking for (and I have done allot of research). I have posted a link to a Picassa photo that hopefully should work.